# Comment utiliser « préposition + quel(le)(s) + nom » dans une question ?

Tags: questions, interrogative

> À la page 180, dans *Advanced French Grammar*, V. Mazet écrit que :
>    When constructing a question: After a preposition you must use the construction : preposition + quel + noun.

L'extrait ci-dessus m'amène à penser que

> 1.En quel format est-ce que ceci existe ?

est fausse et qu'il faut formuler:

> 2.En quel format ceci existe-t-il ? (Plus tôt, j'avais écrit de manière incorrecte : <s>En quel format existe ceci ?</s>)

Je ne suis jamais tombé sur cette règle. Ainsi, j'ai recherché sur Google "en quel format est-ce que" qui a entraîné plusieurs succès. Qui a tort ici ?

Comment: Pourrait-on avoir un peu plus de contexte ? Je ne vois pas quel est le problème.

Comment: Absolument. J'ai mis à jour mon post original.

Comment: En (préposition) + quel + format (nom). Pour le reste de la question, oui, il y a plusieurs possiblités.

Answer (score 4):

***Si,*** comme je le crois, on fait référence ici à une construction du genre *Sous quel général avez-vous servi?* c'est tout simplement l'extension normale de l'interrogation avec *qui*, et elle correspond aux relatives avec lequel/laquelle: *le général sous lequel j'ai servi...* Ce ne sont pas des constructions très communes, mais elle sont parfaitement naturelles. Circulez, rien à voir ici.

**Ajout:**

*En quel format existe ceci?* est incorrect, l'autre formulation pour cette question est celle de l'inversion: *En quel format ceci existe-t-il?* (*est-ce que* et l'inversion sont presque toujours deux formulation possible pour une question oui/non).

Comment: Merci de votre réponse. Je vous demande pardon pour ne pas avoir spécifié que mon poste ne trait de que la formulation des questions. Je viens de mettre à jour mon post original.

Comment: Deux fois, _En quel format existe ceci?_, je suppose que le deuxième devrait être _En quel format ceci existe-t'il?_, mais je ne sais que faire de la parenthèse, l'inversion sans pronom de reprise étant au contraire relativement rarement possible.

Comment: Dort-il?/ est-ce qu'il dort? etc. sont toujours deux possibilités pour ce type de question, tout simplement. Je n'ai pas la moindre idée de ce que "l'inversion sans pronom de reprise" est censé vouloir dire.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: Existe-t-il.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, exact — ça fait partie des erreurs que je commets souvent sans arriver à les éviter.

Comment: @Circeus, _Dort_il?_ est une inversion sans pronom de reprise, _En quel format ceci existe-t-il?_ est une inversion avec [pronom de reprise](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronom-de-reprise) (le sujet est _ceci_ qui est repris par le _il_).

Comment: ARGH! J'étais tellement certain de l'avoir écrit correctement dans ma réponse que je ne l'ai même pas relu après le commentaire (ou je n'ai pas remarqué) corrigé.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. D'après vos commentaires, j'ai corrigé la phrase #2. Après la rectification, la phrase #1, est-elle correcte actuellement ?